# Uncaught Type Error: Object[object Object] has no method timepicker

Tags: jquery

Hi there i am trying to implement a basic timepicker example and I encounter:
`Uncaught Type Error: Object[object Object] has no method timepicker`

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" href="js/jquery.ui.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#id1').timepicker();
     });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Input: <input id="id1" type="text" name="fullname"><br>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of priority must be the following:

1. jQuery.js
2. Everything that depends on jQuery.

It looks like you got that wrong (looking at your code in the question). Change it to this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load jQuery first!

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```